# Huawei Media Pad T5 AGS-W19, usb tethering missing, please help!

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode, tethering, usb-tethering

As per manual, there is usb tethering under settings. Followed exact instructions, but the option of "usb tethering" doesn't exist even when searched. The only option is "USB" which is currently in MTP, tried PTP, Charge only, Midi, all does not give me "usb tethering".

Developer options, turned on USB debugging, "usb tethering" still missing.

Tried restarting, factory reset, changed usb cable, changed usb ports, changed computers, updated drivers on pc, all of which did nothing to give me "usb tethering" on my tablet. I have an exact LTE version of the tablet, it has "usb tethering". The wifi version as per wifi version manual indicates there is usb tethering.

Please help?

Comment: Could you quote the WiFi version of the manual? I could only find online manuals that say "*Use USB to share **mobile data**: Use a USB cable to connect your device to a computer. Open Settings, go to Wireless & networks > Tethering & portable hotspot, and enable USB tethering to start sharing your mobile data.*" (emphasis mine) on page 64 and  "*Mobile data is not supported on Wi-Fi only tablets*" on page 63.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/D1JVS3ciTbS.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjrmPKP8KbwAhWIKzQIHZxlAhgQFjADegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw3KcPJFlinI9U7xq-fHseUw

Comment: The page number is different, but the text is the same. I could only infer that the USB tethering feature is not included in the WiFi-only tablet... at least from the UI, though maybe there's a hackable way to do it.

Comment: I don't see why the manual say there  is usb tethering and it isn't. I feel like there some options diabled. I searched online, and I see other tablets having same issues after certain system updates. Anyhow, suggestions on hackable way?

Comment: Try settings up adb and then run this adb command from your PC when the device is connected via usb: `adb shell svc usb  setFunctions rndis`. If your Windows PC still doesn't get Internet connectivity than USB tethering might not be supported at all on your device.